# Apply configuration to specific projects in gradle build script

Tags: groovy, gradle

I have a gradle project that has java applications as well as android applications.

```
root/
  build.gradle
  settings.gradle
  java1/
  java2/ 
  android1/
  android2/
  java3/
```

etc.

What is the best practice for structuring my build script? I am a total gradle novice and am migrating the project from maven to gradle.

I wanted to do something instead of

```
configure(subprojects) {}
```

to apply plugins and other specific things.

such as

```
configure(java1, java2, java3) { // java specifics }
configure(android1, android2) { // android specifics }
```

I am probably approaching this from the wrong way.

More explicitly I need to apply the plugin java only for the java projects and the android plugin for the android projects.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are multiple ways, depending on what you want... Some examples:

```
// Configures just project java1
project(":java1") { ... }

// Configures projects java1 and java2
["java1","java2"].each { name ->
  project(":$name") { ... }
}
```

You can use normal groovy to find/iterate over all the projects.

Comment: Kind of a groovy novice as well. I do like your approach better as it is more scalable. Thanks

Comment: Actually after testing, this won't work. The script is complaining about the fact that it cannot find root (in this case the directory name that is the root of the project). 

Project with path ':root' could not be found in root project 'root'.

I simply copy and pasted 

// Configures projects java1 and java2
["java1","java2"].each { name ->
  project(":$name") { ... }
}

The error line points to project(":$name")

Comment: After the fact, I went ahead and looked up the gradle/groovy apis and was able to write a method to return subsets of subprojects that I can pass into the configure() method. That works. Thanks

Answer (score 18):

```
configure(subprojects.findAll {it.name == "java1" || it.name == "java2"}) {
```

[Under the filtering section in the guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sub:project_filtering)

Hope this helps someone else out.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `||` not `&&`?

Answer (score 3):

Another option:

```
configure([ project(':sub1'), project(':sub2'), ... ]) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The shortest and easiest option:

```
configure(subprojects.findAll()) {
   if (it.name.equals('MY_PROJECT')) {
     ...
   } else {
     ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach...

In the settings.gradle you do define your projects like this:

```
gradle.ext.javaProjects=[]
gradle.ext.androidProjects=[]

javaProject('java1')
javaProject('java2')
javaProject('java3')
androidProject('android1')
androidProject('android2')

def javaProject(String name) {
    gradle.ext.javaProjects.add(name)
    include ":$name"
}

def androidProject(String name) {
    gradle.ext.androidProjects.add(name)
    include ":$name"
}
```

Now you can reference those in your root build.gradle:

```
def javaProjects = subprojects.findAll {gradle.ext.javaProjects.contains(it.name)};
def androidProjects = subprojects.findAll {gradle.ext.javaProjects.contains(it.name)};

configure(javaProjects) {
...
}
configure(androidProjects) {
...
}
```

Maybe thats overkill... but i usually have the project definition method in my settings.gradle anyway. E.g. if you want to put all java projects under a java folder you could define things like this:

```
def javaProject(String name) {
    gradle.ext.javaProjects.add(name)
    include ":$name"
    project(":$name").projectDir = file('java/'+ name)
}
```